# How to resolve Azure SignalR Service Cert Authority Invalid

Tags: signalr, azure-signalr

I'm using Azure SignalR Service and am getting the error message below:

```
WebSocketTransport.js:85 WebSocket connection to 'wss://mysignalrservice.service.signalr.net/client/?
hub=contestchange&id=my_id&access_token=my_token' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID
```

[image: Chrome Console Error]

Any ideas on how I might resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this was due to setting the SignalR feature flag `Service Mode` to `Serverless`. Once I set it back to `Classic` it started working as expected.